# Show that $\lim_{n\to ∞} |a_n| = |a|$ if $a_n\to a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence with $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$. 
>   Show that  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n| = |a|$$
>   Then state and disprove the converse statement.

In order to prove that I would use the following inequality $||a|-|b|| \le |a-b|$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. $(a_n) \rightarrow a$ and thus by definition there exists a $N$ such that
$$|a_n-a|< \epsilon \text{ for all } n \geq N$$

Since I want to show that $|a_n| \to |a|$,  I apply the inequality from above and get 
$||a_n|-|a|| \le |a_n-a| < \epsilon$ for all $n≥N$ following $||a_n|-|a||< \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. As this hold for any $\epsilon$ by definition $|a|$ is a limit of $|a_n|$.

My first question would be if this proof is right.
My second question is concerning the converse statement. I don't quite get what the converse statement here is. Normally if $P\Rightarrow Q$ the converse is $Q\Rightarrow P$ so is the converse
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n| = |a| \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to ∞} a_n = a\quad?$$

Comment: This all looks right to me. Given the converse as you've stated, can you see a counterexample?

Comment: The converse is false because $|a|=|-a|$.

Comment: @SimonS Never approve an edit if it changes the Title to MathJax-only. This is what the improve edit button is for.

Comment: @AlexR I would also prefer you not overwrite all of my other edits to the question ;-)

Comment: ..and fixing spelling and some formatting. Anyway. Appreciate your answers.

Comment: @SimonS I've merged your edit with mine now and added some additional improvements so everything should be fine now.

Comment: If you want to avoid $\varepsilon$-type reasoning observe that the claim is obvious for $a=0.$ Next use $$-|a_n-a|\le |a_n|-|a|\le |a_n-a|$$ and apply the sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The proof of convergence is very fine. Note that we usually use $\epsilon$ or $\varepsilon$ and not $e$ for the small constant, but that's just cosmetic.

The simplest counter-example for the converse is $a_n = (-1)^n$. $|a_n| = 1$ so $|a_n| \to 1$ but $a_n$ doesn't converge (because it alternates).